# ADALiOS - how to refresh accessToken silently?

Tags: ios, adal

I'm using ADALiOS v3.0.0-pre.2 to connect to Azure AD B2C and authorize a given user. I successfully obtain an `accessToken` for the user, who gets prompted with UI to login in the process. I use the `acquireTokenWithScopes` method on `ADAuthenticationContext` instance to do so.

Somewhere down the line, I want to make sure that the `accessToken` I obtained earlier is still valid and hasn't been revoked. So, I use `acquireTokenSilentWithScopes` to check. However, I get an immediate error back saying:

> Error raised: 10. Additional Information: Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain Details: The user credentials are need to obtain access token. Please call the non-silent acquireTokenWithResource methods.

What's the right usage of this API such that the token gets silently refreshed or throws an error only when it has been revoked on the server side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215128/the-user-credentials-are-need-to-obtain-access-token-please-call-the-non-silent

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a problem for me. Right now it appears that the framework is trying to use nil as the key with which to store the token data in the cache, which fails. Then there is nothing to find in the cache later on. Still investigating... but thanks for the link - I appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: can you provide logs to us to help investigate? Feel free to send them to brandwe@microsoft.com

Comment: thanks for the offer, @BrandonWerner! unfortunately i cannot share logs with you. something about lawyers and NDAs - not my decision. that said, i figured out what needed to change to get the silent refresh call working. i'll post my findings below. it would be really helpful if you could please look over it and let me know whether i've discovered actual bugs, whether i'm running into mis-configured servers, or whether i'm just using the API in a way that's different from its intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to beat `acquireTokenSilentWithScopes` into submission by making the following changes to ADALiOS v3.0.0-pre.2.

## Change #1:

**ADUserIdentifier** has the following class method:

```
+(BOOL) identifier:(ADUserIdentifier*)identifier matchesInfo:(ADProfileInfo*)info
```

In it, there are the following lines of code:

```
NSString* matchString = [identifier userIdMatchString:info];
if (!matchString || [matchString isEqualToString:identifier.userId])
{
    return YES;
}
```

For one reason or another, `matchString` can sometimes come back as `NSNull` and calling `isEqualToString:` method on it will throw. I changed it thusly:

```
id matchString = [identifier userIdMatchString:info];
if (!matchString || ![matchString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] || [matchString isEqualToString:identifier.userId])
{
    return YES;
}
```

This seems like a legit bug in the framework that's worth fixing.

## Change #2:

When a token is received from AD, ADALiOS tries to store that value in the cache. At some point, it calls **ADTokenCacheStoreItem**'s `userCacheKey` property, which is defined as follows:

```
-(NSString*)userCacheKey
{
    switch (_identifierType)
    {
        case OptionalDisplayableId:
        case RequiredDisplayableId:
            return _profileInfo.username;

        case UniqueId:
            return _profileInfo.subject;
    }
}
```

In my case, I use `RequiredDisplayableId` to identify users. In the switch statement above, that translates to `_profileInfo.username`, which, in turn, returns the `preferred_username` value from the user profile dictionary. For me that value is not set. So, `userCacheKey` returns `NSNull` and the caching mechanism fails.

The values that are set in the user profile dictionary are `name` and `tid`. This could be a server misconfiguration, but I worked around the issue by changing the return value of this method to `_profileInfo.friendlyName` (which maps to `name` in the user profile dictionary).

## Change #3:

The **ADKeychainTokenCacheStore**, which I use as the concrete **ADTokenCacheStoring** cache of choice, exposes a `sharedGroup` property that allows multiple applications to share common keychain secrets. By default, `sharedGroup` is set to `com.microsoft.adalcache`. However, since the class is currently private, there is no way to override this value. Also, having that value set requires the iOS app to declare the shared group name in its entitlements. Without these entitlements properly configured, setting values into the keychain fails. So, to work around this issue, I manually set the default `sharedGroup` value to `nil` in the **ADKeychainTokenCacheStore** class itself. I suspect eventually this class will be exposed by the framework as public, but currently that's not the case so I had to hack into it.

## Change #4

When I request an auth token from the AD server via the ADALiOS framework, I do so using a policy and a set of scopes. The framework code uses this policy/scope pair to create a lookup key and see if any tokens for that key have already been cached. If none are found, the code contacts the server as expected. Once the server returns an auth token, the framework attempts to cache the value. It constructs a brand new policy/scope key object. However, this time, it uses the policy and scope values that are *returned by the server*, not the ones I passed in. And, for some reason, the server returns those values to `nil`. As a result, the new policy/scope key that gets constructed for storage is valid but *different* from the one I used to look up the cached token initially. So, while the caching operation succeeds, next time I try to look up the auth token using my valid policy/scope pair, the lookup fails.

This may, once again, be a server misconfiguration issue.

Regardless, to fix the problem, I now reset the policy and scope values in the response from the server to the original values I used to generate the server request in the first place. This happens in the following method in `ADAuthenticationContext(TokenCaching)`:

```
- (void)updateCacheToResult:(ADAuthenticationResult*)result
              cacheInstance:(id<ADTokenCacheStoring>)tokenCacheStoreInstance
                  cacheItem:(ADTokenCacheStoreItem*)cacheItem
           withRefreshToken:(NSString*)refreshToken
```

After all these changes, getting the AD auth token and refreshing it silently seems to work as expected. I'm a little worried about how much I needed to hack into the codebase to make it work. It would be helpful if some MS folks could direct me as to whether these changes were warranted or whether there is a more straight-forward solution.

**UPDATE:**
It turns out that you don't need to hack into **ADKeychainTokenCacheStore** directly (change #3 above). The **ADAutheticationSettings** class exposes a method for you to do so thusly:

```
    [[ADAuthenticationSettings sharedInstance] setSharedCacheKeychainGroup:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Brandon Werner from the Azure Active Directory team. I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44170226/1232116 for the specific question asked.